# Reading Date times from Excel to Python using Pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas, datetime, types

I'm trying to read from an Excel file that gets converted to python and then gets split into numbers (Integers and floats) and everything else. There are numerous columns of different types.

I currently bring in the data with

```
pd.read_excel
```

and then split the data up with

```
DataFrame.select_dtypes("number")
```

When users upload a time (so 12:30:00) they expect for it to be recognized as a time. However python (currently) treats it as dtype object.

If I specify the column with parse_dates then it works, however since I don't know what the data is in advance I ideally want this to be done automatically. I`ve tried setting parse_dates = True however it doesn't seem to make a difference.

I'm not sure if there is a way to recognize the datatime *after* the file is uploaded. Again however I would want this to be done without having to specify the column (so anything that can be converted is)

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does what I need

```
for column_name in df.columns:
    try:
        df.loc[:, column_name] = pd.to_timedelta(df.loc[:, column_name].astype(str))
    except ValueError:
        pass
```

This tries to convert every column into a timedelta format. If it isn't capable of transforming it, it returns a value error and moves onto the next column.

After being run any columns that could be recognized as a timedelta format are transformed.

Answer (score 0):

If your data contains only one column with dtype `object` (I assume it is a string) you can do the following:

1) filter the column with dtype `object`

```
import pandas as pd
datatime_col = df.select_dtypes(object)
```

2) convert it to seconds

```
datetime_col_in_seconds = pd.to_timedelta(datatime_col.loc[0]).dt.total_seconds()
```

Then you can re-append the converted column to your original data and/or do whatever processing you want.

Eventually, you can convert it back to datetime.

```
datetime_col = pd.to_datetime(datetime_col_in_seconds, unit='s')
```

if you have more than one column with dtype object you might have to do some more pre-processing but I guess this is a good way to start tackling your particular case.

Comment: I forgot to say but users can upload as many columns as they like.

Comment: as long as they are all of dtype object (i.e. string) the suggested approach should work. You just have to do it for all columns that you get from the df.select_dtypes(object) command. like in a for loop or something like that.

Comment: They are not all of the same type. So the times will be mixed in with numbers and strings.